# Using a Microsoft Chart (WinForm) in Mono

Tags: c#, linux, winforms, mono, mschart

I am using a chart for a simple WindowsForm example.  Works well in Windows.
I am compliling the solution on my Windows platform using XBuild.  When I try to run the executable with Mono (version used 4.2.3.4) on my Linux machine (Red Hat 6.8), I am getting an error message:

```
    Unhandled Exception:
   System.NotImplementedException: The method or operation is not implemented.
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart.BeginInit () <0x40a79f40 + 0x00017> in <filename unknown>:0 
   at Data_grid.Form1.InitializeComponent () <0x40a6e680 + 0x002cd> in <filename unknown>:0 
   at Data_grid.Form1..ctor () <0x40a4c9f0 + 0x00027> in <filename unknown>:0 
   at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) Data_grid.Form1:.ctor ()
   at Data_grid.Program.Main () <0x40a0bd90 + 0x0002f> in <filename unknown>:0 
   [ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.NotImplementedException: The method or operation is not implemented.
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart.BeginInit () <0x40a79f40 + 0x00017> in <filename unknown>:0 
   at Data_grid.Form1.InitializeComponent () <0x40a6e680 + 0x002cd> in <filename unknown>:0 
   at Data_grid.Form1..ctor () <0x40a4c9f0 + 0x00027> in <filename unknown>:0 
   at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) Data_grid.Form1:.ctor ()
   at Data_grid.Program.Main () <0x40a0bd90 + 0x0002f> in <filename unknown>:0
```

I am a newbie at both C# and Linux.  Any input would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

WinForms on Mono are abandoned and a lot of methods aren't implemented like that one.

You can use (per example) GTK# or Eto.Forms which are mantained gui toolkits with multiplatform support.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're using the [Mono project's **Windows Forms** implementation](http://www.go-mono.com/status/status.aspx?reference=4.0&profile=4.0&assembly=System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization). **WinForms** was abandoned by Xamarin before being finished. Hence the exception you obtain: **NotImplementedException**.

You have two alternatives.

1. Use an external project, such as [ZedGraph](https://sourceforge.net/projects/zedgraph/).
2. Draw the chart yourself. If you want to go this path, you can take the **Chart** class in this [WinFormsDemo code in GitHub](https://github.com/baltasarq/WinFormsDemo) (disclaimer: it's mine), as example.